# put random points in a square region while maintaining a minimum distance (Python)

Tags: python, 2d, coordinates

I have a square region of size [a, a] containing real number coordinates. I want to fill it with with N random points. The conditions is that the distance between any two points has to be greater than a minimum distance D.

The brute force way is to keep generating a random point until it meets the condition. But, to check the condition with all other points is kinda expensive. Is there a better algorithm to do this?

Comment: Strictly speaking, after the first point, each additional point isn't randomly placed into the space.

Comment: @Andrew yeah you're right about that. But I just want the next random number to be placed randomly in the space available at that point

Answer (score 4):

If you had some grid overlay on top of the points, you could generate a circle whose radius is the minimum distance around each point, and flag each grid cell that's in those circles. Then, randomly pick a non-flagged grid cell to generate a point at, then repeat until there's no spaces left.

Comment: That's a really nice solution. You could use hexagonal close-packing to do that.

Comment: This was my thought, also, more generally, for fixed values of `a` and `D`, the odds of being able to place N points falls very quickly as `N` increases

Comment: Actually that's exactly what I was doing till now. But I can no longer use a grid cause I need to work in the continuous domain now.

Comment: @corvo so you can't simply translate/convert the grid coordinates into continuous ones? You could theoretically put the point anywhere inside a free "pixel", it doesn't have to be right in the dead center, so the location of the point doesn't have to be rigidly quantized to the grid's coordinates.

Comment: @RandomDavis Yes, that would give me values in the continuous domain, but I can only flag an entire cell in the grid. So, let's say a portion of the cell satisfies the distance constraint and the other portion doesn't. But I will have to flag the entire cell. So, that would mean falsely flagging that region of the cell. So, its not the solution I want. But yeah, It's definitely an improvement over my current grid approach and the size of the false region can be decreased by creating smaller and smaller grids to whatever precision vs computation trade off someone is willing to make.

Comment: @corvo if the flagged grid cells completely contain the radius, then any point in any non-flagged cell is guaranteed to be outside of the range. Yes, there would be jagged regions where parts of the continuous domain are falsely flagged as being within the radius, but that's the point really, it's not a perfect method but it'll still give correct results, and it's potentially a lot faster than randomly placing points and checking the distance to every single one. Just depends on how accurate you need to be versus how fast.

Comment: @RandomDavis yes, that's exactly what I meant by "precision vs computation" tradeoff.

Answer (score 2):

<s>I am not sure if there is a an analytical solution to your problem</s>. Actually, there might be, as suggested above :-).

However, the brute force method you suggested can be made more efficient by using an [R-tree](https://rtree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html), and a performing nearest neighbors search.
Basically, I would insert a point in random, look for its nearest neighbors and move it according to the distance from those NN.